# Colorbox in WordPress - Getting Started

Tags: jquery, wordpress, colorbox

I'd like to use ColorBox to open some inline HTML in my WordPress page. I've downloaded the plugin (this one, to be exact: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jquery-colorbox/) and have that installed and now I have no idea what to do next. I believe I need to input one of the .js files into header.php, but I'm not sure which file to use. I'm also not entirely sure what sort of code needs to go into the actual page to make the effect work.

If there's a "ColorBox for Dummies" set of instructions out there, feel free to point me in the right direction. I just need some help getting started with this.

Comment: Are you using a standard WordPress theme? All the provided themes, and themes from decent designers, will already include the necessary calls ([wp_head()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head) and [wp_footer()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer)) to allow plugins to insert their Javascript into a page automatically. If that's happening (view the source of a page of your blog and search for "colorbox", you should see the include) then you're good to go, and just need to configure Colorbox on the admin page to work how you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow [these instructions](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jquery-colorbox/installation/).

Once you activate the plugin from the *Plugins* menu, there is a settings button on the same page that corresponds to the ColorBox plugin.

Normally, you don't need to do anything to implement the plugin beyond activating it and setting properties on its settings page.